# How can i find website visitor's location(only city) using javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to fetch the city name  where a visitor is accessing my website. i want to show some results according to the location(city name). I have tried so many codes but they were not fetching the correct city name.
programming Language: javascript or Php

Please help.

Comment: see http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/visitor-location-in-php

Comment: geolocation APIs are not always perfectly accurate. It depends on how complete the data from the ISP to the location service is.

Comment: @AndyHolmes: how to use that?

Comment: @Vishalmiddha You'll have to look into the documentation for the API

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to implement it. Either using javascript or php. The problem with javascript is all browsers does not support this feature and required client permission to trace location. If user does not want to share his location then javascript will prevent it.
So best way to use php and you can check out http://www.ipinfodb.com/ this url.

This is free ip db list and you can also find php api to implement it. You have to create free account on this site and get a api key and you can use php code like below

```
    $location_str = file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<your_api_key>ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
    echo $location_Str;
```

you can replace 'ip-country' with 'ip-city' in url if you want city info.

Answer (score 0):

You can...

- use the Geolocation API: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html - **Pro**: very accurate. **Con**: the user has to allow the usage of his geolocation.
- or you can use a service like http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php to get the location via IP. **Pro**: Works also with old browsers and without permission. **Con**: Inaccurate (the IP details don't point to the correct location in all cases).

Comment: "Pro: very accurate" — It's only as accurate as the location system the browser uses. If it has a GPS, then its very accurate. If it does GeoIP, then it probably isn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But compared to a geolocation got by IP it is still a very good result, not least because more and more devices come with GPS. (And also it is worthless if the user does not share his location. ;-))